# VBA search through listbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that searches the exact value from text box and highlights that but how do i make it search even partial strings like values containing 3 letters or more and return them as search results too.

```
Sub search()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer


    With UserForm1.ListBox1
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle
        .ListIndex = -1
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti


        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            For j = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1
                If UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = .Column(j, i) Then
                    .ListIndex = i
                    .Selected(i) = True
                End If
            Next j
        Next i


    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to search for a string in a string, use `InStr()`:

`If InStr(1, "Test", "es", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with changing

```
If UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = .Column(j, i) Then
```

to

```
If InStr(1, .Column(j, i), UserForm1.TextBox2.Text, vbTextCompare) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
If UserForm1.TextBox2.Text Like Left(.Column(j, i), 3) & "*" Then
```

this will compare first 3 characters of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
UserForm18.ListBox1.Clear

For i = 0 To ListBox3.ListCount - 1
   If InStr(LCase(ListBox3.List(i)), LCase(TextBox1)) Then ListBox1.AddItem ListBox3.List(i)
Next i
```